# Equivalent condition for a collection of subsets to be a base for a topology

Tags: general-topology

I wish to prove the following claim.

**Claim.** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Then a collection of subsets of $X$, $\sigma$ is a base of $\tau$ if and only if:

1. Every $x\in X$ is contained in at least one set in $\sigma$. (That is, $\sigma$ covers $X$).
2. For all $B_1,B_2\in \sigma$, we have $B_1\cap B_2$ can be written as a union of elements of $\sigma$.

Certainly it is obvious that $\sigma$ being a base implies the conditions (1) and (2). However, I have been having more trouble with the other way round.

I can see that for any set $U\in \tau$, we will have $U\subset\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}B_\alpha,$ for some indexing set $A$. This follows from (1), but I am unsure how (2) helps us prove that $U$ can be written as a union of base elements.

Any guidance would be useful.

Note: I had recently asked a similar question to this, but realised I made a fundamental typo which invalidated comments and answers, so I have posted this as a new question with the correct information.

Comment: Note that you probably just mean that $\sigma$ is a basis for a topology on $X$, not necessarily one that generates $\tau$. (Your conditions make no reference to $\tau$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is false as stated, because you start with a fixed $(X,\tau)$.

In order to get a base *for that topology* we at least need the base elements to be open themselves so $\sigma \subseteq \tau$, or else any $B$ that is not open will be in the topology generated by $\sigma$ but not in $\tau$...

But even that extra requirement is not enough: let $(X,\tau)$ be the Sorgenfrey line, so $X=\Bbb R$ in particular and we could choose $\sigma$ the collection of all open intervals (which are indeed Sorgenfrey open), and obey the two axioms. But they only generate the smaller Euclidean topology, not $\tau$.

You can salvage it by omitting $\tau$ altogether and start with a set $X$ and a collection $\sigma$. Then these two conditions are necessary and sufficient for the set of unions of subcollections of $\sigma$ to form **some** topology on $X$. Try to prove that fact instead.